# Looping through the parts of a non-contiguous selection in MS *Word* VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2013

> I have a macro in MS Word 2013 VBA (***not*** Excel) that toggles the selected text's highlight color.  Code looks like
>   this:
>
> ```
> If Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = WhtColor Then Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight Else Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = WhtColor
> ```
>
> That works great for continuous/contiguous selections.  But, if I
>   select, say, 4 non-contiguous rows in a Word table (say, rows 5, 12,
>   15, and 19), the macro highlights only the last row selected.
>
> How do I get the HighlightColorIndex to apply to all "parts" of the
>   noncontiguous range, or, how do I loop through the different "parts"
>   of the range and apply the HighlightColorIndex to each part?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288424 - don't know how up-to-date this is though

Comment: That solved the problem.  But, the question is not really a duplicate given what the actual goal of the code was.  I have updated the question above with the solution thanks to the information at the link offered by @Tim Williams.

Comment: Sorry about that - I didn't fully read the linked page before posting it.  I re-opened your question, so you should now be able to answer it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web page that Tim Williams points to ([support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288424](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288424)) gives a clue about how this is possible. But, that link *does* show that one cannot loop through a non-contiguous selection.

Nevertheless, what that link also shows is that Font formatting *can* be set for a non-contiguous selection, but not for a range object.

Here is the revised code that *does* work for a non-contiguous selection:

```
If Selection.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WhtColor Then Selection.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic Else Selection.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WhtColor
```

That code will change the background color to the target color selected (although I had to change the color codes from Wd constants to WdColor constants).

The only drawback with this approach is that I do not know a way to search for text whose background color has been changed, whereas you *can* search for text that is highlighted.

Anyway, thanks, @Tim Williams for the helpful link. Hope the above helps someone else who just wants to change font properties and does not actually have to loop through the separate pieces of the selected range.

Comment: Nice find @DRC used it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46106637/3451115  (sadly the link to MS is now dead)

Comment: @SlowLearner -- clever application of the idea at that post.  Nice.