# wdtitleword - use vba to apply to more than one word

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Word it's easy to use vba to apply a highlight to more than one string, word, sentence etc after the user of the document has Ctrl-selected a bunch of them.
However, when I Ctrl-select a few words and run the following statement, only the last of my selected words is changed.
Is there a way to apply wdtitleword to more than one selected word? 
Thanks.

```
sub a()
Selection.Range.Case = wdTitleWord
end sub
```

Comment: It works for me... can you give more info?

Comment: @SlowLearner Doesn't work for me - only the last selected set of words is modified.  Did you try Ctrl-selecting several sets of words, or did you just select a single set?  (E.g. I used a paragraph of "Abds `jsdhfksahdf sdfkhskd` sdkf sjakh skdf `ksfh ksdafh` skdfh sdkjh fksdh `skdhg kdhg khdg` kshg kasgh" (with the code highlight representing the selected parts, and with `ksfh ksdafh` being the last selected of those) and only the `ksfh ksdafh` was modified.)

Comment: @YowE3K Oh - non-contiguous... no that does not work. And selection only seems to return the last set of words...  I thought: `Shift + Ctrl + Arrow`.... doh

Comment: @YowE3K https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407694/looping-through-the-parts-of-a-non-contiguous-selection-in-ms-word-vba (of course the link to the MS info is dead)

Comment: @SlowLearner The amount of Word VBA that I know could be written on a postage stamp, so I will have to leave this to someone else to think about.

Comment: @YowE3K I think you're too modest... anyway had a quick think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
Sub changeNonContigCase()

    ' Find the non-contig selection
    If Selection.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic Then
        Selection.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = whtcolor
    End If

    ' Find and process each range with .Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WhtColor
    ActiveDocument.Range.Select
    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart

    With Selection.Find
        .Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = whtcolor
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue

        Do While .Execute
            ' Do what you need
            Selection.Range.Case = wdTitleWord

            ' Reset shading as you go
            Selection.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic

            ' Setup to find the next selection
            Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

This works, but is indirect. I don't think there is a more direct way to achieve this. You can modify to avoid resetting existing formatting that you need to preserve. Until now I didn't even know that it was possible to select a non-contiguous range in MS Word, pity it is not easier to work with in VBA.

Comment: As I said, I know very, very little Word VBA - so I don't understand half of what it is doing, but I do know that worked for my sample test so hopefully will work for the OP.

Comment: @YowE3K Yes... MS Word is a very different beast from Excel, thanks for testing :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the responses. I tried your code but all I get is new shading on the non-contiguous words; none are changed to title case - not even the last one. (I changed 'whtcolor' to 'wdcolorpink' to make things stand out) The code only runs as far as 'Do while . Execute' then stops. I'm using Word 2010 if that's relevant.

Comment: I'm also using Wd2010.  Try it on a simple test document.  @YowE3k & I both verified that it works....

Comment: Thanks SlowLearner, but my doc is one paragraph created with "=rand(1) <Enter>" - and all I get is black shading on my words and the cursor at the start of the doc.

Comment: Whoa - I closed Word, re-opened it and now the code works. So if it stops working again, that's a whole new ball game I suppose. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: That's a little strange but glad its working. Please mark as an answer and feel free to upvote 

Comment: @hmm I forgot to tag you in my comment above 

Comment: @hmm to accept an answer press the tick symbol that is near the top left of the answer and to upvote press the up arrow next to the answer :-) Cheers,

Comment: @SlowLearner - have ticked and upvoted (but not shown as a vote as I'm quite new on here).
Also - it's stopped working again - I don't get title case but am left with the non-contig words highlighted (in my case aqua). I also have a macro to highlight non-contig words that uses the same change of BackgroundPatternColor - it was working OK this morning, then I opened a different document, it now ends up with the non-contig words highlighted aqua, i.e. it's not getting to the 'dowhile .execute / Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow. Any ideas? All macros are in Modules under Normal.

Comment: It might be that the active document is changing. I'm not near a PC. I'm sure that it is a simple fix - google for techniques to avoid using Active document