# Acting on multiple Selection.Range objects in Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to surround all the selected text on a page with quotation marks, but when I run the code it only affects the last selection on the page. My code also unbolds all the selected text, and that part is working fine. My code is as follows:

```
With Selection.Range
    Selection.Range.Bold = wdToggle
    .Text = Chr(34) & .Text & Chr(34)
End With
```

Comment: It's not possible to work with the individual objects of a set of non-contiguous selections using VBA. Basically, if you can't do something with the selection as an end-user, you can't do it with VBA. You can bold multiple selections as an end-user by clicking the bold button. But you can't put quotes around each selected item. This is just how it was designed. There's also no way to pick up the individual Ranges of a multiple selection.

Comment: Oh well. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Selection.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAqua
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAqua
    .Format = True
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    .Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
    If .Characters.Last = vbCr Then .End = .End - 1
    .InsertBefore Chr(147) 'Chr(34)
    .InsertAfter Chr(148) 'Chr(34)
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Note:** I've used smart quotes, but you can use straight quotes if you prefer.

Comment: Thankyou for this! For those trying to work out how to get the range of the selection being worked on inside the Do While loop, I can offer this which I've tested: change the line "With ActiveDocument.Range" to "With adr" and define adr on the line before with "Dim adr As Range: Set adr = ActiveDocument.Range".  Then inside the Do While loop "adr" will be the range it found (one piece of the multi-range selection). You can't simply use ActiveDocument.Range in there as it returns the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46106637/3451115

It only works if you are not using highlights throughout the document. The idea came from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36413118/3451115

In a nutshell you use highlights as a temporary marker to search for and post-process (for want of a better expression). Find highlights allows you to loop through what was selected.

Comment: This seemed like it would work, but it actually results in an infinite loop. This seems to be caused when modifying the text inside the current selection because this does make all the text not bold, but it just continues to wrap a single selection with quotes

Comment: It works, but you might have to break it down to smaller steps. Perhaps try with the working example and add complexity from there. Failing that, edit the question (or ask a new one) with the failing code!